# Config sentinel throttle interval

Tags: laravel, sentinel, cartalyst-sentinel

How to change sentinel user time interval.
When I make changes in IlluminateThrottleRepository in throttle folder userinterval from 900 to 3600. Still throttle denied for 900 second .
How to make changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to publish the config file

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Cartalyst\Sentinel\Laravel\SentinelServiceProvider"
```

Then in config/cartalyst.sentinel.php change the throttling interval to what ever you want